# Get the no of weeks from date duration with overlapping scenario

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, c#-4.0

I need to calculate the count of total assigned week and total benched week for an employee.

An employee is assigned in different projects in some time duration which will always start from Monday and always end on Friday. Monday to Friday will be considered as 1 week.There cant be more than 2 week duration for any project. Any overlapping weeks of assigned status should be adjusted. If employee staus  is assigned and that time duration overlaps or falls with any of the benched week duration then that week duration for benched status should not be counted at all .

Below are the relevant scenario as below.

```
"AssignedHistory":[ 
   {"Project":1,"status":"Assigned","Startdate":"01/03/2022", "Enddate":"01/07/2022" }, 
   {"Project":2,"status":"Assigned","Startdate":"01/10/2022", "Enddate":"01/14/2022" }, 
   {"Project":3,"status":"Assigned", "Startdate":"01/10/2022", "Enddate":"01/21/2022" },
   {"Project":4,"status":"Assigned", "Startdate":"02/21/2022", "Enddate":"02/25/2022" },       
   {"Project":5,"status":"Bench","Startdate":"01/17/2022", "Enddate":"01/21/2022" },
   {"Project":6,"status":"Bench","Startdate":"02/07/2022", "Enddate":"02/11/2022" }
   {"Project":7,"status":"Bench","Startdate":"02/21/2022", "Enddate":"03/04/2022" }    
]
```

Here I need to find the count of total assigned week and total benched week for an employee, and expected result should be :

```
Total assigned week:4
Total benched week :1



     Since 1 week of assigned status is overlapping for 2 projects(no2 and no 3) from 10th Jan to 14 Jan so project 2 and 3 together will be counted as 2 .Also for assigned week of  project 3  it is overlapping with  benched week of  project 5  from 17th Jan to 21st Jan so in that case bench week for project 5 will be counted as 0.Similarly for assigned week of project 4,duration from 21st feb to 25th feb is overlapping or falls under benched week of  project 7 so in this case project 7 will be counted as 0.So only we have project 6 for benched week which doest not overlaps with any of the assined project duration.
```

Thats  why total benched count will be 1.

This is how I am thinking.

```
 var assignedweek = AssignedHistory.Where(x => new []{"Assigned"}.Contains(x.status)).ToList();
    var benchedweek = AssignedHistory.Where(x => new []{"Bench"}.Contains(x.status)).ToList();
     
    List<DateTime> AssignedWeeklist = assignedweek
        .SelectMany(a => {
            DateTime firstSunday = a.Startdate.AddDays(-(int)a.Startdate.DayOfWeek);
            DateTime lastSunday = a.Enddate.AddDays(-(int)a.Enddate.DayOfWeek); 
            int weeks = (lastSunday - firstSunday).Days / 7 + 1;
    
            // Enumerate one Sunday per week
            return Enumerable.Range(0, weeks).Select(i => firstSunday.AddDays(7 * i));
        })
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
        
        List<DateTime> BenchWeeklist = benchedweek
        .SelectMany(a => {
            DateTime firstSunday = a.Startdate.AddDays(-(int)a.Startdate.DayOfWeek);
            DateTime lastSunday = a.Enddate.AddDays(-(int)a.Enddate.DayOfWeek); 
            int weeks = (lastSunday - firstSunday).Days / 7 + 1;
    
            // Enumerate one Sunday per week
            return Enumerable.Range(0, weeks).Select(i => firstSunday.AddDays(7 * i));
        })
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
        
        int assignedweekcount = AssignedWeeklist.Count();
        int benchedweekcount = BenchWeeklist.Except(AssignedWeeklist).Count();
```

It is giving correct assign week count  But it is giving incorrect bench week count if there is overlapping bench week with assigned week.
Any way to do this?

Comment: could you show how you build your variable AssignedHistory?

Comment: Actually  I have created these variable by fetching the details from mongo db collection with some filter condition.Is anything wrong in it?

Comment: i dont understand your logic for benched or i misunderstand......the explanations and the result waited are different? for me you have only one week (projet 3 and 5) overlapped between benched and assigned so the result waited is so 1...so you dont say the same thing in your explanations??

Comment: I have updated my statement for having clear understandings.So logic should be  even one week of assigned week duration falls or overlap with any of the benched week duration then benched week duration should be counted as 0 or does not come into consideration .

Comment: ok i understant better i'll modify my answer

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the logic of your calcul on benchweek, you have to keep the sunday date by project:

( i have OS French, so the dates in sample are in format DD/MM/YYYY and not MM/DD/YYYY)

```
        var AssignedHistory1 = new List<Projet>()
        {
            new Projet(1,"Assigned","03/01/2022", "07/01/2022" ),
            new Projet(2,"Assigned","10/01/2022", "14/01/2022" ),
            new Projet(3,"Assigned","10/01/2022", "21/01/2022" ),
            new Projet(4,"Assigned","21/02/2022", "25/02/2022" ),
            new Projet(5,"Bench", "17/01/2022", "21/01/2022" ),
            new Projet(6,"Bench", "07/02/2022", "11/02/2022" ),
            new Projet(7,"Bench", "21/02/2022", "04/03/2022" )
        };
        var AssignedHistory2 = new List<Projet>()
        {
            new Projet(1,"Assigned","17/01/2022", "28/01/2022" ),
            new Projet(2,"Bench", "10/01/2022", "21/01/2022" )
        };
        var AssignedHistory3 = new List<Projet>()
        {
            new Projet(1,"Assigned","07/02/2022", "18/02/2022" ),
            new Projet(2,"Bench", "14/02/2022", "25/02/2022" )
        };

        var listsamples = new List<List<Projet>> { AssignedHistory1, AssignedHistory2, AssignedHistory3 };
        for(int i = 0; i < listsamples.Count;i++)
        {
            calculate(listsamples[i], $"Sample Assigned{i+1}");
        }

        void calculate(List<Projet> AssignedHistory, string txt)
        {
            var assignedweek = AssignedHistory.Where(x => new[] { "Assigned" }.Contains(x.Status)).ToList();
            var benchedweek = AssignedHistory.Where(x => new[] { "Bench" }.Contains(x.Status)).ToList();
            List<DateTime> AssignedWeeklist = assignedweek
            .SelectMany(a =>
            {
                DateTime firstSunday = a.StartDate.AddDays(-(int)a.StartDate.DayOfWeek);
                DateTime lastSunday = a.EndDate.AddDays(-(int)a.EndDate.DayOfWeek);
                int weeks = (lastSunday - firstSunday).Days / 7 + 1;

            // Enumerate one Sunday per week
            return Enumerable.Range(0, weeks).Select(i => firstSunday.AddDays(7 * i));
            })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

            List<List<DateTime>> BenchWeeklist = benchedweek
            .Select(a =>
            {
                DateTime firstSunday = a.StartDate.AddDays(-(int)a.StartDate.DayOfWeek);
                DateTime lastSunday = a.EndDate.AddDays(-(int)a.EndDate.DayOfWeek);
                int weeks = (lastSunday - firstSunday).Days / 7 + 1;

            // Enumerate one Sunday per week
            return new List<DateTime>() { firstSunday, lastSunday }.Distinct().ToList();
            })
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

            int assignedweekcount = AssignedWeeklist.Count();
            var benchedweekcount = 0;

            foreach (var l in BenchWeeklist)
            {
                var found = false;
                foreach (var it in l)
                {
                    if (AssignedWeeklist.Contains(it)) found = true;
                }
                if (!found) benchedweekcount++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"AssignedWeek{n} count: {assignedweekcount}, BenchWeek{n} count: {benchedweekcount}");
        }
```

result:

```
AssignedWeek1 count: 4, BenchWeek1 count: 1
AssignedWeek2 count: 2, BenchWeek2 count: 0
AssignedWeek3 count: 2, BenchWeek3 count: 0
```

Comment: i dont think  intersection will give correct result for these scenario

Comment: yes i know after your explanations

Comment: @vicky i have updated new solution

Comment: thankyou so much..I have tested with 2,3 scenario and it is working.I am only concern about its performance as for loop iteration can be painful when there can be 50-100 assigned week count for some cases.

Comment: it is not giving correct result for benched count  if assigned week is 01/17/2022-01/28/2022 and benched week is 01/10/2022 - 01/21/2022.Benched week should be 0 here  since 17 to 21 is overlaping with bench week but it is showing 1

Comment: your logic is complex...could you edited your question and put 2 or 3 samples with  the explanations of results waited..

Comment: Yes I agree with you that logic is little complex but only thing that needs to be considered is that If any assigned week is overlap with benched week then benched week should not be considered at all.For ex:if assigned week is 01/17/2022-01/28/2022 and benched week is 01/10/2022 - 01/21/2022 then Benched week should be 0 here since 17 to 21 is overlaping.Sly if assigned week is 02/07/2022-02/18/2022 and benched week is 02/14/2022 - 02/25/2022 then Benched week should be 0 here since 14 to 18 is overlaping.
Is it make sense?

Comment: do u still have some confusion?

Comment: sorry but i have the right result?? see my answer edited with your samples, i have no benchWeek 1 as result...